# Why cant i use `"+` in vim?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

Previously, whenever I typed `"+yy` in vim, it yanked a line to the system clipboard.

I reinstalled the OS again, and, when I try to do the same now the input disappears after entering `+`.

Steps:

1. I type `"` and vim shows `"`
2. I type `+` and vim disappears

How do I make it accept `"+yy`?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! If you press yy when the quote disappears, does it yank to the clipboard or the default register?

Comment: Got it, anyways it doesnt yank to system clipboard but register. Also checkout my answer

Answer (score 2):

After talking to my friend in Discord about Vim. I found out that my clipboard is disabled. `:version` shows `-clipboard`.

I did some research and found the `vim-gnome` package that fixes it. However, since I hadn't installed gnome, I found an alternative called `vim-gtk3`. I installed it, and now I can copy to the system clipboard.